# JavaCV DNN RetinaFace Model how to get the face and landmark information

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, javacv

I am using the JavaCV DNN module to build a face detector using the RetinaFace model. Here is the model: https://github.com/serengil/retinaface
I am referring to the OpenCV C++ version to develop the Java version. However, I am not very familiar with Java and Python, so when I use JavaCV, I am having trouble understanding the network output.

Here is the code I have used:

```java
String model="model/retinaface/mnet.caffemodel";
String proto="model/retinaface/mnet.prototxt";
Mat image = opencv_imgcodecs.imread(testPhoto);
net = opencv_dnn.readNetFromCaffe(proto, model);
Mat newImage = new Mat();
resize(image, newImage, new Size(640, 640));
Mat blob = blobFromImage(newImage, 1.0, new Size(640, 640), new Scalar(104.0, 117.0, 123.0, 0), false, false, CV_32F);       
net.setInput(blob);
Mat output = net.forward();

StringVector outLayerNames = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
for (long i=0; i< outLayerNames.size(); i++) {
    LOGGER.info("Index {} out layer name: {}", i, outLayerNames.get(i).getString());
}

LOGGER.info("Output mat: {}", output);
LOGGER.info("Output mat dimensionality: {}", output.dims());
LOGGER.info("Output mat size width: {}", output.size().width());
LOGGER.info("Output mat size height: {}", output.size().height());
LOGGER.info("Output mat size 0: {}", output.size(0));
LOGGER.info("Output mat size 1: {}", output.size(1));
LOGGER.info("Output mat size 2: {}", output.size(2));
LOGGER.info("Output mat size 3: {}", output.size(3));
LOGGER.info("Output mat rows: {}", output.rows());
LOGGER.info("Output mat cols: {}", output.cols());
```

here are the debug output information:

```
Index 0 out layer name: face_rpn_bbox_pred_stride32
Index 1 out layer name: face_rpn_landmark_pred_stride32
Index 2 out layer name: face_rpn_cls_prob_reshape_stride32
Index 3 out layer name: face_rpn_bbox_pred_stride16
Index 4 out layer name: face_rpn_landmark_pred_stride16
Index 5 out layer name: face_rpn_cls_prob_reshape_stride16
Index 6 out layer name: face_rpn_bbox_pred_stride8
Index 7 out layer name: face_rpn_landmark_pred_stride8
Index 8 out layer name: face_rpn_cls_prob_reshape_stride8
 Output mat: org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat[width=-1,height=-1,depth=32,channels=1]
Output mat dimensionality: 4
Output mat size width: 4
Output mat size height: 1
Output mat size 0: 1
Output mat size 1: 4
Output mat size 2: 80
Output mat size 3: 80
Output mat rows: -1
Output mat cols: -1
```

The code does not have any errors, but I do not know how to get the face and landmark information. Can someone help me? I have googled for a long time but have not found any valuable information.

Comment: what *is* the output? [edit] and add it to the post. -- javacv is a separate project, not related to opencv. keep that in mind if you expect *opencv* apis to exist in *javacv*.

Comment: I used JavaCV its a wrapper for OpenCV.  not used OpenCV API. The output is the object: `org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat`, When I using debug found is very hard to understand, its like a pointer to a native object.

Comment: opencv has its own java bindings, so I don't see the advantage to javacv. yes, it's always the C++ compiled library underneath.

Comment: looks like you got an (1,4,80,80) shape output from inference. what shape of output did you expect? the list of layers seems to include not just output layers... or there isn't just one output layer

Comment: Its should have mult-layes output. Here are the output description: https://docs.openvino.ai/archive/2021.3/omz_models_model_retinaface_resnet50.html.   I just want to know for this output format how to get the face box and landmark information from  `org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat`

Comment: looks to me like the forward() call returns the last of the eight output tensors (`face_rpn_cls_prob_reshape_stride8` because that's the only one with that shape; their docs contain typos), so you'll have to look for a way to get at the others. the network will still have all those activations. -- there _might_ be code already, specific to this model, that converts the network's outputs into usable data. for popular models, that's usually the case.

Comment: Would you have a working example in C++? I would be able to translate that to Java.